# Symfony Exception (Class not found) only on development and production servers

Tags: php, symfony, exception, laravel

I am getting the following error in my Laravel 4 project ONLY on the production and testing servers. Everything works fine on my local machine:

`{"error":{"type":"Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalErrorException","message":"Class 'Intercom\\IntercomBasicAuthClient' not found","file":"\/www\/htdocs\/laravel\/app\/ACME\/Services\/IntercomService.php","line":26}}`

I have tried everything! I even deleted the composer.lock file and the whole vendor directory and did a fresh install via composer install. Nothing helped.

I ran `php artisan clear-compiled`, `php artisan dump-autoload` and `php artisan optimize` ...nothing helped :(

The class is physically in the right location and it works perfectly fine on my local machine.
The class is also perfectly referenced in the IntercomService.php with a use statement like so:

`use Intercom\IntercomBasicAuthClient;`

This is the composer.json:

`{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "https://github.com/intercom/intercom-php"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "laravel/framework": "4.2.*",
        "intercom/intercom-api-client": "dev-master"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "app/commands",
            "app/controllers",
            "app/database/migrations",
            "app/database/seeds",
            "app/tests/TestCase.php"
        ],
        "psr-0": {
            "ACME": "app"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable"
}`

Comment: What `namespace` are you using before your `use`?

Comment: I use: `namespace ACME\Services;`

Comment: Can you paste line 26 where you're calling IntercomBasicAuthClient ?

Comment: $this->intercom = IntercomBasicAuthClient::factory(array(...

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution! The problem was in the Intercom PHP Package. In the src/ folder of the package they were writing the folder of the intercom namespace in lowercase letters like so:

```
src/intercom/...
```

Since `intercom` doesn't match the namespace `Intercom` it didn't work!

However, on my local Mac it did work, since I guess the Mac is case-insensitive and doesn't care?!

I have been pulling my hair over this one and hope this helps others with this kind of issue...

**Make sure that your Namespace matches the folder case in which it resides.**

Comment: Hi, I am also facing the same or similar problem. Here is my question, please help me here, if you have any idea.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38832607/php-intercom-not-working-after-updating-composer